# How to merge discontinuous memory

Tags: memory, driver, windows-kernel

In my driver, I need to merge some discontinuous memory to one entire continuous memory area, and I don't want to allocate a new buffer to copy. So I need to map memory to a specific address. Do I need to probe the memory which is unused and unallocated ?

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work correctly as I expected.

```
g_p = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(DRIVER_OBJECT));
g_pMdl = IoAllocateMdl(pDriverObject, sizeof(DRIVER_OBJECT), FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool(g_pMdl);
MmProbeAndLockPages(g_pMdl, KernelMode, IoModifyAccess);
g_pMaped = MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache(g_pMdl, KernelMode, MmCached, g_p, FALSE, NormalPagePriority);

DbgPrint("DriverObject: 0x%p\n", pDriverObject);
DbgPrint("g_p: 0x%p\n", g_p);
DbgPrint("g_pMdl: 0x%p\n", g_pMdl);
DbgPrint("g_pMaped: 0x%p\n", g_pMaped);
```

And here is the result I get from windbg:

```
DriverObject: 0xFFFFAB0C56868E30
g_p: 0xFFFFAB0C50B07AC0
g_pMdl: 0xFFFFAB0C5696B6E0
g_pMaped: 0xFFFFD3812F2FFE30
```

Comment: *I want to map memory to a specific address* - you can not. *Do I need to probe the memory which is unused and unallocated ?* - if want got page fault in nonpage area bsod, yes

Comment: If I can't map, what is the meaning of RequestedAddress? Is this parameter only for UserMode? But AccessMode can be set to KernelMode.

Comment: If AccessMode = UserMode,